# Add Custom Product Grid Created Date And Created By Magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, date, product-grid

In magento 2 admin panel, at product list grid area, i want to add one more grid with date, that date define product create date. so we get idea at which time product was created.

And i also want to add by whom it created, we have so many admin so we want to know by whom that product created.

So we need that 2 column on product grid area in admin side.

Comment: Explain your question a bit more as it is hard to understand your query with this minimum content

Comment: @N.KarthicKannan, In magento 2 admin panel, at product list grid area, i want to add one more grid with date, that date define product create date. so we get idea at which time product was created. and i also want to add by whom it created, we have so many admin so we want to know by whom that product created. so we need that 2 column on product grid area in admin side.

Comment: @JACK can you take a screenshot?

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh which screenshot?
in admin of magento 2 on product catalog list page. i want 2 column.
1)Created Date
2)Created By

I don't think it need any screenshot.

Answer (score 5):

We can find the Create At field in table: `catalog_product_entity`.

So, for this field, we only need to show it:

For example:

app/code/Vendor/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="created_at" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created Date</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">71</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Remember to create registration and module.xml.

**[Note]**

The `create_at` result will be different from database. Because

> As we use default value CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for TIMESTAMP type columns
>   we need to set GMT timezone

`\Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql::connect()`

```
    $this->_connection->query("SET time_zone = '+00:00'");
```

Comment: Thanks for answer @khoa, Can you guide me for Created by column?

Comment: @JACK in this case, hard for us. Because in some cases we cannot track the Created by. For example, products are created by CSV or via command line. But, I have a guide for you. We need to create a new product attribute `Created By`, and then add it via ui component like above. Using `beforeSave` plugin to get the current session for Created By.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to filter product by created date in Magento.

**/MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```
<column name="created_at">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column
```

Or follow this link : [Magento 2 add product created at date to filter product in admin grid](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314279/magento-2-add-product-created-at-date-to-filter-product-in-admin-grid/314280#314280)