# Magento 2 add product created at date to filter product in admin grid

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I want to filter products by date in the admin product grid. Is there any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I Have achieved it by this trick.If any other would-be appreciatable.

We can add the below code on this file :

**/MagentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml**

```
<column name="created_at">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="editor" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

[image]

Filtered Results

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For Magento 2, I've matched the configuration of other columns, and ended up with this (which works for me):

```
<column name="created_at" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="110">
    <settings>
        <addField>true</addField>
        <filter>dateRange</filter>
        <dataType>date</dataType>
        <label translate="true">Created At</label>
    </settings>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to put the following into a new file at `app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml`, which allowed me to specify my preferred date format, and omit the time, which I did not need:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns">
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date" sortOrder="2100">
            <settings>
                <addField>true</addField>
                <filter>dateRange</filter>
                <dataType>date</dataType>
                <dateFormat>dd.MM.y</dateFormat>
                <label translate="true">Created At</label>
                <editor>
                    <editorType>date</editorType>
                </editor>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</form>
```